# symfony doctrine validate entity relations error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two Entities **User** and **Device** with a One-To-Many Bidirectional relationship.

the issue is when in I run this command

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`

I get

`* The association App\Entity\User#devices refers to the owning side field App\Entity\Device#user which is not defined as the association, but as the field.`

`* The association App\Entity\User#devices refers to the owning side field App\Entity\Device#user which does not exist.`

**User** Entity

```
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Device", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $devices;
```

**Device** Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer",name="user_id")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="devices")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $user;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to define user as `association not as a field` in your database table.

Your Device entity should be like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="devices")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $user;
```

The field named `user` should not be there in your table, it will automatically generate a field named `user_id`. You don't need to add it manually.

For more information see [Symfony Doctrine associations](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/associations.html).

Comment: thank you @shaithya-kannan , this answer solved my problem .

Comment: Same here. Thanks.

Comment: For saving new device(s) you can add a new option to the OneToMany: cascade={"persist"}, and for removing the existing device(s) add orphanRemoval=true